# Sending client certificate via WCF to causes an error: "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'"

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an IIS ASP.NET service that needs to make calls to another IIS service via WCF https, where the other service requires a client certificate.

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication), I have added the following code (on the source side):

```
  WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();      
  binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;      
  binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

  m_wcfProxy = new IISSecurityServices.SecurityServiceClient();
  m_wcfProxy.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
  m_wcfProxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(m_wcfProxyEndpointAddress);            
  m_wcfProxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\0\\SslClientCert.cer"); ;
```

The only difference above is that I am loading the certificate (which is the same certificate used by the target service) from a file.

Now, when I make a call, I get the following error:

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

I can't see what I have missed here. Why is this not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to this paragraph of that article.

> In this scenario, the service is hosted under Internet Information
>   Services (IIS) which is configured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
>   The service is configured with an SSL (X.509) certificate to allow
>   clients to verify the identity of the server. The client is also
>   configured with an X.509 certificate that allows the service to verify
>   the identity of the client. The server’s certificate must be trusted
>   by the client and the client’s certificate must be trusted by the
>   server.

On the server-side, hosting the WCF with transport security requires an Https binding in the IIS site binding module, namely, bind a certificate to the port, then expose the service with this port. Besides, please note that we should establish the trust relationship between the server-side and the client-side, that is, install each other’s certificate in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` locally if you are using a self-signed certificate.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: thanks for that.So from [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/02/12/how-to-configure-iis-client-certificate-mapping-authentication-for-iis7/) I assume client side we need *2* certs, 1. We install to say we trust an issuer. 2. A cert from that issuer we send to the server. I did all that, but I still get the same error. I even tried to send the cert I installed (given to be by another dev doing the target server side). But unfortunately it still get the same error.

Comment: The certificate installed by the client should be the one used by the server. The certificate provided by the client should also be installed by the server. How did you generate your certificate? And how do you ensure that the current certificate is issued to the server/client and not replaced with another certificate? The subject of the certificate should match the domain name of the current machine. Can you access the service page (it should be HTTPS) on the client machine and display the security lock logo on the browser?